# When is the adjoint representation of the orthogonal group irreducible?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, orthogonal-matrices

The adjoint representation of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is the exterior product of two fundamentals.

In some cases this is an irreducible representation, e.g. for $n=3$ it is actually equivalent to the fundamental thanks to the invariant tensor $\epsilon_{ijk}$.

In some other cases it is reducible, e.g. for $n=4$ it is the direct sum of two irreducible representations $A_+ \oplus A_-$. Where a tensor in $A_\pm$ satisfies the (anti)self-duality condition
$$
M_{ij} = \pm\, \epsilon_{ijkl} M_{kl}\,.
$$
For what other values of $n>4$ is the adjoint representation irreducible?

Comment: On the Lie algebra level, the adjoint representation is the highest weight representation for the weight = highest root of the root system. This is irreducible if the Lie algebra is simple, i.e. in cases $n=3$ and $n \ge 5$. I assume on the Lie group level, basically the same thing happens. As you say, for $n=4$ it is not, and the cases $n=1,2$ are trivial.

Comment: This answers the question, thanks